# A form of Lagrangian for gravitation

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

In a paper dealing with graviton-photon interactions, the author starts from this Lagrangian for gravitation:

$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{ \sqrt{-g}}{\kappa^2} g^{\mu \nu} \left( \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\, \, \mu \nu} \Gamma^{\beta}_{\, \, \alpha \beta} - \Gamma^{\beta}_{\, \, \mu \alpha} \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\, \, \nu \beta} \right) $$

The factor in the parenthesis should be the **Ricci tensor**, but two terms seem to be missing, the $\partial \Gamma$ terms.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which paper? Which page?

Comment: Skobelev 1975., "Graviton-photon interaction", but it's not that relevant to the question itself.

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00889810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These partial derivatives can be brought to total derivatives